# Set Up the Server Side of Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications

Im my app I need to include push notifications but I don't understand how to start settings things up on the server side.

Does anyone know of an example of server side code that implements a push notification? Which language is preferred for the server implementation?

Comment: This is fully documented by Apple. Is there something specific you need help with?

Comment: I agree with you...
But what I didnt understood is..everyone is writing provider in different languages...
Can we write it in objectiveC also?
Can our data server send something to provider so that provider will fwd it to APN and from then to the device?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please Refer [this link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services) for How to create SSL Certificate for Pushnotification and there is also code for Pushnotification.

Enjoy Coding.....

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at some of the commercial services that manage push notification for you such as [Urban Airship.](http://urbanairship.com/)